# AIR - StageWebView on iPhone

Tags: iphone, flash, apache-flex, mobile, air

I am using Flash Builder 4.5 to build an iPhone app.

In order to display ads I plan to use StageWebView and load a webpage containing the ad code.

Lets say the ad will be 320x50 pixels. So the Actionscript code would look similar to this:

```
adView = new StageWebView();
adView.loadURL("http://www.myadishere.com/ad.html");
var top:Number = navigator.actionBar.measuredHeight + 1
adView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, top, 320, 50);
adView.stage = stage;
```

In the application I have set the **applicationDPI="160"** so the application is displayed properly when run on iPhone3 and iPhone4.
However the content of the StageWebView looks tiny on iPhone4.
If I do **adView.drawViewPortToBitmapData()** the bitmap's size is OK.

So the question is how to make the StageWebView content to scale accordingly, so it looks OK regardless of the screen DPI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 You need to scale by yourself. Here is sample code.


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" width="100%" height="100%" top="0">
    <fx:Declarations>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import mx.core.IVisualElement;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            import spark.components.View;
            import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;

            [Bindable]
            public var htmlText:String;
            public var url:String;
            private var swv:StageWebView;
            private function resizeSWV():void{
                var currentFlexScalingFactor:Number=FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.runtimeDPI/FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.applicationDPI;
                if(swv!=null){

    //swv.viewPort=new Rectangle(0, stage.stageHeight-height*currentFlexScalingFactor-FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.tabbedNavigator.tabBar.height*currentFlexScalingFactor,width*currentFlexScalingFactor,height*currentFlexScalingFactor);

    swv.viewPort=new Rectangle(0, systemManager.screen.height*currentFlexScalingFactor-height*currentFlexScalingFactor-FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.tabbedNavigator.tabBar.height*currentFlexScalingFactor,width*currentFlexScalingFactor,height*currentFlexScalingFactor);

                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:creationComplete>
        <![CDATA[
        swv=new StageWebView();
        resizeSWV();
        swv.stage=stage;


        var htmlString:String=htmlText;
        var urlL:String=url;

        swv.loadURL(url);
        (owner as View).addEventListener(ViewNavigatorEvent.REMOVING,
        function(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void{
            swv.viewPort=null;
            swv.dispose();
            swv=null;
        }
        );
        ]]>
    </s:creationComplete>
    <s:resize>
        resizeSWV();
    </s:resize>
</s:Group>

 This is for TabbedViewNavigatorApplication.
```

Comment: Some of the information here is outdated. But the general idea is the same. It worked well for me 4.6-SDK I'm getting a good stage webview scale now from my nexus one to my galaxy nexus, to my xoom.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following code to your HTML, in the `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=XXXpx, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Substitute the "XXX" with your banner/StageWebView width. That should make the picture appear with the size you intend.

Answer (score 0):

@OMA I think the StageWebView is a little buggy. When (in HTML) I put:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=x.x">
```

the iPhone app crashes. Any '...-scale' crashes the app. Without the '...-scale' instruction it works fine.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320px, height=50px, user-scalable=no"> 
<style type="text/css">

body, html {margin: 0 0; padding: 0 0; overflow: hidden;}
body {width: 320px; height: 50px;}
html {height: 50px;}
```

It kind of works - the ADL show content in incorrect size, however in most cases the iPhone itself shows the ad as it should be. However sometimes the ad is shown in half size - not sure why - it's exactly the same HTML page and the same AS code all the times, however the way the ad is shown varies

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
viewActivate="openSWV(event)"
viewDeactivate="closeSWV(event)">

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="portrait"/>
        <s:State name="landscape"/>
    </s:states> 

    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button icon="@Embed('assets/icons/back.png')" label.landscape="Back" click="navigator.popView()"/>
    </s:navigationContent>

    <s:titleContent>
        <s:Label text="Help" color="#FFFFFF" textAlign="center" fontWeight="bold" width="100%" />
    </s:titleContent>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:String id="_help">
            <![CDATA[
            <html>
            <body>
            <p>Blah blah blah</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            ]]>
        </fx:String>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import flash.media.StageWebView;

            private var _swv:StageWebView;

            private function openSWV(event:Event=null):void {
                _swv = new StageWebView();
                stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeSWV);

                _swv.stage = stage;
                resizeSWV();

                _swv.loadString(_help, 'text/html');
            }

            private function closeSWV(event:Event=null):void {
                stage.removeEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeSWV);
                if (! _swv)
                    return;
                _swv.dispose();
                _swv = null;
            }           

            private function resizeSWV(event:Event=null):void {
                if (! _swv)
                    return;

                var scale:Number = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.runtimeDPI / FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.applicationDPI;

                // align to the right-bottom corner
                _swv.viewPort = new Rectangle(stage.stageWidth - scale * width, stage.stageHeight - scale * height, scale * width, scale * height);

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:View>
```

I align to the bottom-right corner, because I use a [SplitViewNavigator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa367498dc1175407-5e4576591324aa78a9f-8000.html).

If you just want to align to the bottom, just use:

```
_swv.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, stage.stageHeight - scale * height, scale * width, scale * height);
```

Answer (score -1):

First, why do you need to set the DPI manually?  The problem is that the iphone 4 DPI is much higher than 160 (I think it's double that, but don't take my word for it).  Why not just have your application resize based on relative value (percentages) or even have different layout depending on resolution.  You can always check `Capabilities.pixelAspectRatio` to see what's the dpi and change things accordingly.

Again, if it was me, I'd be using percentages for most things.  It resizes better and you have less code overall.

Comment: I can scale the application 'manually', but the problem with the content of the StageWebView still exists.
On iPhone3 the dimensions of the viewPort are 320x50px but on iPhone4 the dimensions are 640x100px - how can I make the content of the webpage to scale to the size of the viewport?

Comment: You could have your StageWebView load up a different sized 'ad' depending on the size of the viewport.  It's either that or have your ad be resizable based on percentages.

Comment: How can I scale the ad (HTML content) based on the percentage? I tried to play with 'viewport' meta tag. It seems that the support for this tag is not implemented in the StageWebView. Unfortunately loading different content depending on the DPI is not an option...

Comment: You can't 'scale' the html content from the StageWebView.  It needs to be done from the HTML being loaded itself.